Can I set up a VPN between a host computer and an Oracle Cloud VM to avoid port forwarding?
TLDR: How can I use an Oracle Cloud server with port forwarding to avoid needing to port forward on my home internet?
I would like to set up game servers (Minecraft, Project Zomboid, ...) on a device on my home network, but am unable to port forward as it is school WiFi.
Is there a way to use an Oracle Cloud server as an intermediary point, with its ports forwarded, to allow the connections to be made correctly?
My idea is something like Radmin VPN/Hamachi on the device and Oracle service for them to communicate and send the traffic correctly. If there is a term I should be looking for I can work it out, I just need a starting point on how to do this.
It would also be cool if this means all the servers would have a static port even if the device moves to a different network.

why are you requiring the use of the Oracle cloud server?

@jsotola: I would assume because they already have one

Set up any kind of IP tunnel or VPN between the two systems. Preferably not a "desktop" VPN but rather something that is meant to run as a long-term service, e.g. the typical choices would be Wireguard or OpenVPN or possibly ZeroTier.
There is no such thing as "port forwarding" to the cloud VM, as the server already has a dedicated public address for itself. (Well yes, Oracle Cloud servers are technically behind NAT, but it's 1:1 NAT so there is still no manual "port forwarding" step for them.)
You do need to set up "port forwarding" from the cloud VM through the VPN to your game server – this is usually done through iptables or nftables 'DNAT' rules.
You also need to make sure your game server replies back to clients through the VPN and not directly (IP routing is not automatically symmetrical – just because connections come in through interface A, doesn't mean that reply packets will be sent out the same way). Depending on what OS the game server runs, the options are:

"Policy routing" on the game server using ip rule (more complex to set up, but lets the game server see original client IP addresses), or,
"NAT hairpin" on the cloud VM using iptables 'SNAT' rules (easy to set up but hides client IPs making them all look the same), or,
on Windows it might actually work by default, I don't know for sure.

(There are already plenty of threads for either of those, e.g. search for "ip rule" and you'll probably find 10+.)
Alternatively: Oracle provides weak x64 servers but fairly powerful ARM64 ones, so if you get the Ampere-based VM, you could run at least the Minecraft server on the cloud VM itself. (Probably the Zomboid server as well? It looks to be Java-based so it should automatically be AArch64-compatible.)

Thank you for the response! I already have a computer that I would like to set everything up on and its just easier for me mentally if I do it on a system I have physical access to. I just wanted to use the oracle cloud service free version to get around having to port forward on the local network, instead port forwarding on the oracle machine and tunnel between the two.
